# 3v3 power for a PCB that takes a 2/3A battery

Tags: pcb, uart

I have a broken one of these: https://fccid.io/J69303MICA/Test-Report/Test-Report-1573814.pdf

I have a 5 pin UART and male to male & female to female jumper wires.

There is a header space on the PCB with 14 holes. I believe the squarish one in the corner is where to connect the 3v3 wire or would it be the outermost pin on JP1? I don't want to damage something else on it ignorantly. Thanks for your time. If my title or question isn't clear, please feel free to correct it.

[image: the box with 14pinholes]
[image: jp1 with 2 pins]

Comment: Why do you link to an EMI test report instead of, for example, a picture of the PCB?

Comment: my data is 17kb/s but i managed to screenshot it small enough. i thought there would be more information in the pdf but hey, not all of us can take the time to read.

Comment: To check the VCC and ground use a Multimeter and probe one leg to a big smd capacitor pin and another to 14 pin header 1 by 1.

Comment: USB UART 3v3 regulators often have minimal current capability so are a bad choice as a power supply.  Safest place to feed power is the battery contacts, anything else would require reverse engineering the circuit.

Comment: alright i will try those things, i do have a power supply that came with a pi0 kit

Comment: "not all of us can take the time to read" ... C'mon, you are not gonna read the document you posted but you expect us who help people voluntarily to do so..?

Comment: i did read it and my answer is not in there or i don't understand it. i ask for help LAST. the thing is, the photo he asked about is in the document. see? do you have anything useful to add?